# Why can't I have duplicate working functions?

Tags: php

I have a config page I am creating in PHP, I have used some code I found to create a dropdown from files found in a folder

```
 <?php 

$folder = '../Pic/Upload'; 

echo '<select name="sabpic">'."\n". 
     dropdown(image_filenames($folder), @$_POST['image']). 
     '</select>'."\n".'</br></br>'; 

function image_filenames($dir) 
{ 
    $handle = @opendir($dir) 
        or die("I cannot open the directory '<b>$dir</b>' for reading."); 
    $images = array(); 
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    { 
        if (eregi('\.(jpg|gif|png)$', $file)) 
        { 
            $images[] = $file; 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle); 
    return $images; 
} 

function dropdown($options_array, $selected = null) 
{ 
global $sabpicname;
    $return = null; 
    foreach($options_array as $option) 
    { 
        $return .= '<option value="'.$option.'"'. 
                   (($option == $sabpicname) ? ' selected="selected"' : null ). 
                   '>'.$option.'</option>'."\n"; 
    } 
    return $return; 
} 

?>
```

Now this works perfectly for "selecting a picture for SAB" and when the page is loaded reads the value in $sabpicname and selects that option as default as expected.

I assumed I could take that same function and modify the $sabpicname to $sickpicname and it would work the same but select the value that was contained in the variable instead..

```
<?php 

echo '<select name="sickpic">'."\n". 
     dropdown(image_filenames($folder), @$_POST['image2']). 
     '</select>'."\n".'</br></br>'; 

function dropdown_sick($options_array, $selected = null) 
{ 
global $sickpicname;
    $return2 = null; 
    foreach($options_array as $option2) 
    { 
        $return2 .= '<option value="'.$option2.'"'. 
                   (($option2 == $sickpicname) ? ' selected="selected"' : null ). 
                   '>'.$option2.'</option>'."\n"; 
    } 
    return $return2; 
} 

?>
```

But no matter what I seem to do, this second dropdown is still taking the selected value that is stored in $sabpicname and not $sickpicname, but from what I can see, its now a seperate function and doesn't reference the $sabpicname variable atall, it's not working, so I'm obviously missing something..

Hope someone can shine some light on what im doing wrong.

Comment: where do you call `dropdown_sick`? The code you provide calls the original `dropdown` function?

Comment: Why not pass it as a parameter then just have the one routine?

Comment: Im quite new to php, so im not too sure how to do that?

Comment: see here for code: http://pastebin.com/HbtzSWJd. Also do not use the closing `?>` at the end of the file. If there are any extra characters after it then you will get a `Headers already sent error` which can be hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, I can see now you say that I was still calling the orignal dropdown, I knew it had to be something stupid..

```
<?php 

echo '<select name="sickpic">'."\n". 
     dropdown_sick(image_filenames($folder), @$_POST['image2']). 
     '</select>'."\n".'</br></br>'; 

function dropdown_sick($options_array, $selected = null) 
{ 
global $sickpicname;
    $return2 = null; 
    foreach($options_array as $option2) 
    { 
        $return2 .= '<option value="'.$option2.'"'. 
                   (($option2 == $sickpicname) ? ' selected="selected"' : null ). 
                   '>'.$option2.'</option>'."\n"; 
    } 
    return $return2; 
} 

?>
```

Thank you Ryan